# Python - AttributeError while passing object as a class parameter

Tags: python, class, object, parameters

It is my first question on StackOverflow.

I am trying to do simple game with GUI using MVC architecture.
I code as it suppose to be, but:

AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'view'

I've checked the code and yt video that i was following,
i haven't found relevant response on other Stackoverflow posts so i stuck on debug
I am novice (first time passing object as an attribute into class), can you help me on how to fix it?

```
from ST_model import Model
from ST_view import View

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self)
    
    def main(self):
        #it starts mainloop()
        self.view.main()
    
    def find_data_for_creature_slotz(self):
        result = self.model.creature_data()
        
        #where is the issue?  :(  oups
        self.view.slot1_description.set(result[0])
        self.view.slot1_photo.set(result[1])
        self.view.slot2_description.set(result[2])
        self.view.slot2_photo.set(result[3])
        self.view.slot3_description.set(result[4])
        self.view.slot3_photo.set(result[5])
        self.view.slot4_description.set(result[6])
        self.view.slot4_photo.set(result[7])
        self.view.slot5_description.set(result[8])
        self.view.slot5_photo.set(result[9])
        self.view.slot6_description.set(result[10])
        self.view.slot6_photo.set(result[11])
```

and  top part  form ST_view.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class View(tk.Tk):

    PAD = 5
    
    def __init__(self, controller):

        super().__init__()
        
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.title("StarCraft Tournament")
        self.iconbitmap(r"terran_icon.ico")
        
        #self.value_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot1_description = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot1_photo = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot2_description = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot2_photo = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot3_description = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot3_photo = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot4_description = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot4_photo = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot5_description = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot5_photo = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot6_description = tk.StringVar()
        self.slot6_photo = tk.StringVar()        
        
        self._make_main_frame()
        self._make_architecture()
        self._make_Creature_frame_for_players()
        self._fill_creature_slotz()
```

Comment: Ask yourself when you define `self.view`, and when you get the error. Which comes first?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't get it #Bryan Oakley
Can show it on the example?
Ir woudl be handy.
I'm advancing with my programme, and recently have similar problem:
_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'slot1_photo_label'